# How to run "fsck -y" on next boot in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, boot, fsck

In Ubuntu and derivatives (specifically Linux Mint 17.2), is there a setting in a config file somewhere to run "fsck -y" on boot?

I lost power, and the computer successfully rebooted, but I just want to run fsck to take care of any potential issues before they actually cause trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in a configuration file; just drop a `forcefsck` file in `/`:

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

This will force a check on the next boot.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Bionic... :-|